# Bind two APK together

Tags: android, file, bind, apk

I got my game source and i would like to bind `.apk` with my game. 
The `apk` must run in background, and of course the game should run normally.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You can archive this only by moving source code of second `apk` to you main `apk`

Answer (score 0):

you can add your application source code to your current application and then use the manifest to make them two different applications just add this to your manifest.

```
        <activity
        android:name=".YourClassName"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```